# How to pull a Sharepoint List with a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sharepoint, synchronization

I would like to enable a rails app to pull from a sharepoint list in order to update a model.  Has anybody meshed up these two things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use the SharePoint Web service? you have to use SOAP library 
to access the wsdl and to use the specified credential

http://yoursharepoint-site/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl

There's multitude of web-service methods you could use to manipulate list on List.asmx web service.

I was implementing a code in PHP for it, and this link that help me to get started to access the web-service and use `GetListItems` method

http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/reading-a-sharepoint-list-with-php/
you'll get the idea

Comment: That looks like it is the best(only?) method of doing it.  I could do something silly with opening it with access as a linked table, outputting to powershell and then saving as a csv, or maybe ironruby?

Comment: Just found out this one http://vspug.com/dwise/2008/01/10/accessing-sharepoint-list-data-as-xml/ yet another option :)